# How to remove characters from auto-numbering in InDesign cross referencing?

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, character, numbering, cross-reference

my document has autonumbered headings styled as following:

**1)** Numbered Heading level 1

**1.1)** Numbered Heading level 2
...

The auto-numbering is set as **^#)^>** for heading 1 and **^1.^#)^>** for heading 2

When I create a cross-reference it appears like this:

.... my text refer to chapt. **1)** ...... please refer to par. **1.1)** ....

but I'd like to have someting like this:

.... my text refer to chapt. **1** ...... please refer to par. **1.1** ...

without the closing brackets **)**.

Is there any way to get this?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Dario

Comment: How about a grep style that targets brackets and sets their font size to 0? Might work....

Answer (score 0):

Referencing to the *Paragraph Number*, `<paraNum/>`, in a *Cross-Reference* seems to always include all the characters of the *Number* field of the numbered list, except for `,.;:` (I don't know if there are additional ignored characters).

The only solution I can come up with is to remove `)^>` from the *Number* field and add the closing parenthesis and the en space manually to each header.